# Keydown event not excuting in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, onkeydown

im trying to create a simple game as a starter project, for the start and basics of the project i need one of the objects i created to move according to the input of the user (arrow keys). i tried searching online for solution, everyone said that focusable property must be set to true, and so i did, but it didn't help, it seems that with canvas this does work, but for this project i need the grid layout
any help will be appreciated, im very new to this,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer gameTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    bool goleft, goRight, goUp, goDown;
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        Gameboard.Focus();
        gameTimer.Tick += GameTimer_Tick;
        gameTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000); 
        gameTimer.Start();
        
    }

    private void GameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if  (goleft == true && Grid.GetColumn(yuval) > 0 )
        {
            Grid.SetColumn(yuval, Grid.GetColumn(yuval)-1); ;
        }
        if (goRight == true && Grid.GetColumn(yuval) > 9)
        {
            Grid.SetColumn(yuval, Grid.GetColumn(yuval) +1); ;
        }
        if (goUp == true && Grid.GetRow(yuval) > 0)
        {
            Grid.SetRow(yuval, Grid.GetColumn(yuval) + 1);
        }
        if (goDown == true && Grid.GetRow(yuval) > 9)
        {
            Grid.SetRow(yuval, Grid.GetColumn(yuval) - 1);
        }

    }

    
    private void Keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       
        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {  
            goleft = true;               
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            goRight = true;
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            goUp = true;
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            goDown =true ;
        }
    }

    private void Keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            goleft = false;
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            goRight = false;
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            goUp = false;
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            goDown = false;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="tutorial.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tutorial"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1100" Width="800">
<Grid x:Name="Gameboard" Width="800" Height="800" Focusable="True"   HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" Margin="0,10,0,0" ShowGridLines="True" KeyDown="Keyisdown" KeyUp="Keyisup" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle x:Name="yuval" Height="80" Width="80" Fill="Brown" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column = "6" ></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="TEDDY" Height="80" Width="80" Fill="BlueViolet" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="8" ></Rectangle>
               
    
</Grid>
```